# Get Total Photo Count in a published post via Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently trying to get the total photo count in a published post via Facebook Graph API. I have tried

> me/albums?fields=count,name

but this is counting the number of photos in an album. Thanks in advance

[For example, total photo count is four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0gHu.png)

Comment: whats your trying code?

Comment: me/albums?fields=count,name

Comment: You want to check the attachments of the post. There is not count property available for that, so you will have to fetch the data and count the entries on your end.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $count =0;
 $ALLalbums = $facebook->api('/me/albums?fields=id'); 
 $pics = array();
 foreach ($ALLalbums['data'] as $album) {
 $pics = $facebook->api('/'.$album['id'].'/photos?fields=source,picture');
 $pics[$album['id']] = $pics['data'];
}  
//Albums
foreach ($pics as $album) {
//Count Pics Inside each album
foreach ($album as $img) {
$count++;
// you can get image as well by $img['source'];
}
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Hi, are the photos in a post considered as an album?

Comment: @KirentherenRavindra i did not understand you, give me your code, also you can  change this according to your requirements its easy.but update with your code